# while passing dynamic value through click event it showing undefined in console

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

In check box calling setAssignment function where passing empId dynamically but showing this.empId in the console in undefined how to resolve it

```
    <p>Manage Team for this course</p>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search employee"  [(ngModel)]="searchText"
    (input)="search()" class="mr-2 mb-2"/>
     <span> <strong>    Expected EndDate: </strong>  </span><input type="date"/>
       <div *ngFor="let employee of employeeList.sortedList index as i">
         <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between mt-3">
          <div class="col-6">
           <h5>{{employee.fullName}}</h5>
           <h6>{{employee.designation}}</h6>
          </div>   
          <div class="col-2">
            <i class="far fa-calendar fa-3x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mt-2">
              <input type="checkbox" checked id="checkbox"  (click) ="setAssignment(i)" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary "  >
            Assign to
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In ts file

```
setAssignment(empId:Number){
    console.log(this.empId)
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the *ngFor directive as below

```
*ngFor="let employee of employeeList.sortedList; let i=index"
```

Hope this should work.